# Angular component not refreshing when variable is changed

Tags: angular, typescript, rust, tauri

I hope this is not a duplicated question... I've been looking for a solution for the whole night.
I'm writing a project for the university and they want me to write kind of a data monitor, that displays data from another application.
We have to use rust, so I thought I could use Tauri to make the UI job easier.
The problem I'm facing is the following:
From angular I register the callback to the `add_data` event with the `listen` method. From there I update an attribute with the value received from the event.
The frontend is only displaying that element, but when it is updated, nothing happens to the frontend
Here is my code:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    title = 'trader-visualizer-tauri-2';

    out: string = "out";

    ngOnInit(): void {
        listen('add_data', (event: TauriEvent<number>) => {
            console.log("add_data event received");
            this.out = event.payload.toString();
        })
    }
}
```

```html
<main>
    {{out}}
</main>
```

[image: This is what I see]

Is there a way to force re-render the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `listen` is a function from a JS library you're using. When using such functions and updating your properties from inside their callbacks, **Angular does not know** that the values have changed and that's why you need to notify Angular to detect the changes.

It is pretty easy to do. Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in your constructor and at the bottom of `listen`, call its cdRef's `detectChanges` method.

```
// Inject ChangeDetectorRef
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

...

ngOnInit() {
  listen('add_data', (event: TauriEvent<number>) => {
    console.log("add_data event received");
    this.out = event.payload.toString();

    // And add the following
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  })
}
```

To learn more about Angular Change Detection, here's a resource: https://indepth.dev/posts/1058/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular